# convert local based weekly store timings to GMT weekly timing

Tags: node.js, lambda, timezone, maps, serverless

Logic to convert weekly timings from **local time-zone to GMT** for restaurants in a food delivery app using Node.js.

For instance I am taking input as seconds according to weekdays and time-zone is GMT-6 in the following format.

This is a night restaurant which opens Monday - Saturday, from 10:00 PM (79200 secs) - 1:00 AM (3600 secs).

```
"timing": {
        "Monday": [{
            "from": 79200,
            "to": 86400
        }],
        "Tuesday": [{
            "from": 79200,
            "to": 86400
        },
        {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 3600
        }],
        "Wednesday": [{
            "from": 79200,
            "to": 86400
        },
                {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 3600
        }],
        "Thursday":[ {
            "from": 79200,
            "to": 86400
        },        {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 3600
        }],
        "Friday": [{
            "from": 79200,
            "to": 86400
        },        {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 3600
        }],
        "Saturday":[ {
            "from": 79200,
            "to": 86400
        },        {
            "from": 0,
            "to":3600
        }],
        "Sunday":[]
    },
```

After converting to GMT it should look something like this. (4:00 AM (14400 secs) - 7:00 AM (25200 secs))

```
"timing": {
        "Monday": [],
        "Tuesday": [{
            "from": 14400,
            "to": 25200
        }],
        "Wednesday": [{
            "from": 14400,
            "to": 25200
        }],
        "Thursday":[ {
            "from": 14400,
            "to": 25200
        },        {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 3600
        }],
        "Friday": [{
            "from": 79200,
            "to": 86400
        }],
        "Saturday":[ {
            "from": 14400,
            "to": 25200
        }],
        "Sunday": [{
            "from": 14400,
            "to": 25200
        }]
    },
```

This is my current code for the conversion, I am using maps timezone api to get the timezone offset

```
const convertTimingtoGMT = async (timing, location_lat_lon) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const timestamp = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
        const location = location_lat_lon.lat.toString() + ',' + location_lat_lon.lon.toString();
        var offset;
        var gmtTiming = {};
        https.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=${location}&timestamp=${timestamp}&key=${MapsAPIkey}`, (res) => {
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                offset = JSON.parse(d.toString());
                for (const day in timing) {
                    if (!([day] in gmtTiming)) gmtTiming[day] = [];
                    timing[day].forEach(slot => {
                        let temp = {};
                        const from = slot.from - offset.rawOffset;
                        const to = slot.to  - offset.rawOffset;
                        // from cases
                        if (from < 0) temp.from = addSlot(0, gmtTiming, day, from);
                        if (from >= 0) temp.from = from;
                        // to cases
                        if (to >= 86400) temp.to = addSlot(86400, gmtTiming, day, to);
                        if (to < 86400) temp.to = to;
                        //edge cases
                        if (from > 86400 || to < 0) return;
                        gmtTiming[day].push(temp);
                    });
                };
                resolve(gmtTiming);
            });
        }).on('error', (e) => {
            reject(e);
        });
    });
};

const addSlot = (sec, slot, day, offset) => {
    let week = new Array(7);
    week[0] = "Sunday";
    week[1] = "Monday";
    week[2] = "Tuesday";
    week[3] = "Wednesday";
    week[4] = "Thursday";
    week[5] = "Friday";
    week[6] = "Saturday";

    const weekIndex = week.indexOf(day);
    const nextDay = typeof week[weekIndex + 1] === 'undefined' ? "Sunday": week[weekIndex + 1];
    const prevDay = typeof week[weekIndex - 1] === 'undefined' ? "Saturday": week[weekIndex - 1];

    if(offset >= 86400) {
        if (!([nextDay] in slot)) slot[nextDay] = [];
        slot[nextDay].push({
            from: 0,
            to: offset - 86400
        });
    }
    else if (offset < 0) {
        if (!([prevDay] in slot)) slot[prevDay] = [];
        slot[prevDay].push({
            from: 86400 + offset,
            to: 86400
        });
    }

    return sec;
};
```

Please do let me know if there is any better approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

> Please do let me know if there is any better approach for this.

There's a general fallacy inherit in such operations, in that they assume that the offset for the local time will never change.  In actuality, many time zones around the world regularly change their offsets for two different reasons:

- Start or stop of Daylight Saving Time (also known as Summer Time in some areas)
- Changes to the Standard Time offset, occasionally introduced by governments

You can read more about this in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), under the heading "Time Zone != Offset".

You had said `"...and time-zone is GMT-6..."` - but in actuality, one can only say that any given point in time has an offset of GMT-6 (or more correctly stated, UTC-6).  Thus, converting a recurring schedule in its entirety would be invalid, because the offset for one occurrence might be something else entirely.  For example, if the time zone is actually [`America/Chicago`](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/chicago), then the offset would sometimes be UTC-6, and other times be UTC-5.

You should change your application to *not* try to convert an entire schedule to UTC.  Instead, store the weekly recurrence schedule in terms of the local time at the desired time zone, and also store the time zone identifier (such as `'America/Chicago'`).  If you need to convert any particular date to UTC, then you will have all of the information you need to convert correctly, even if the offset for that date is different than the offset for some other date.